# ORDER BY then GROUP BY a datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT t.date_time, COUNT(t.submission_id) AS click_count, s.title, s.first_name, s.family_name, s.email, ut.ukip_name, a.advertiser_name 
FROM recards.tracking t 
INNER JOIN submissions s ON t.submission_id = s.submission_id 
INNER JOIN form_settings fs ON t.form_id = fs.form_id 
INNER JOIN advertisers a ON t.advertiser_id = a.advertiser_id 
INNER JOIN db2829.ukip_titles ut ON fs.ukip_title_id = ut.ukip_title_id
WHERE t.advertiser_id = 621 
GROUP BY t.submission_id 
ORDER BY t.date_time DESC
```

However, of course, as the `ORDER BY` is done after the `GROUP BY`, I only get the first record, where as I need the last. Investigating, I read about using `MAX()` on the column during the `SELECT`, but that does not work with `datetime` types.

Is there another work around? Maybe embedding `SELECTs` within `SELECTs`? What I have above is about as far as my `MySQL` knowledge goes, unfortunately!

Comment: "but that does not work with datetime types." Why not?

Comment: What makes you think `MAX()` doesn't work with `datetime` values?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: @darkajax Because I've tried, and I don't get any output whatsoever with `SELECT MAX(t.date_time)` ...

Comment: @jzd, I need to order the rows by most recent `datetime` and _then_ group them, so that I am left with the most recent record, not the record put in to the database first.

Comment: @MatthewPeckham so could there be multiple records with the same `date_time` value? if so, what's your criteria to determine which one you want?

Comment: @darkajax It simply wanted the most recent _date/time_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was just forgetting the `AS` after the `MAX()`, with `MAX(t.date_time) AS top_time` it works fine.

My full query working:

```
SELECT MAX(t.date_time) AS top_time, COUNT(t.submission_id) AS click_count, s.title, s.first_name, s.family_name, s.email, ut.ukip_name, a.advertiser_name 
FROM recards.tracking t 
INNER JOIN submissions s ON t.submission_id = s.submission_id 
INNER JOIN form_settings fs ON t.form_id = fs.form_id 
INNER JOIN advertisers a ON t.advertiser_id = a.advertiser_id 
INNER JOIN db2829.ukip_titles ut ON fs.ukip_title_id = ut.ukip_title_id
WHERE t.advertiser_id = 621 
GROUP BY t.submission_id 
ORDER BY top_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just grouping by  t.submission_id  and nothing else, so this query will not work.  The other attributes need to be added to the `GROUP BY` or need to be eliminated from the `SELECT`.

As far as ordering add `MAX(t.date_time)` or `MIN(t.date_time)` to your `SELECT` and then `ORDER BY` that result either ascending or descending.